# How to fix edit interface getting only first word of a column in table in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

My edit interface `edit.blade.php` only gets the first word of the name from my database, this is what the `index.blade.php` looks like [image]

and when i click on the edit icon of the 3rd line it leads me to `edit.blade.php` which gives me this

[image]

"Nom d'établissement" textfield only gets the first word from the database

Everything looks fine in the database:
[image]

this is my `edit.blade.php` form:

```
     <form method="post" action="{{ route('etablissements.update', $etablissement->id) }}">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
        <div class="col-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nom">Nom Etablissement :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value={{ $etablissement->nom }} />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">E-Mail :</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value={{ $etablissement->email }} />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="quantity">Telephone:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" value={{ $etablissement->telephone }} />
        </div>
      </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmer</button>
      </form>
```

this is `edit` function in the controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
  $etablissement = Etablissement::find($id);

  return view('etablissements.edit', compact('etablissement'));
}
```

and this is `update` function in the controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $request->validate([
        'nom'=>'required',
        'email'=> 'required',
        'telephone' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);

    $etablissement = Etablissement::find($id);
    $etablissement->nom = $request->get('nom');
    $etablissement->email = $request->get('email');
    $etablissement->telephone = $request->get('telephone');
    $etablissement->save();

    return redirect('/etablissements')->with('success', 'Utilisateur édité');
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quote the value attribute.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ $etablissement->nom }}" />
```

Without quotes, the second word in`$etablissement->nom` is interpreted as another attribute rather than part of the value of the `value` attribute.

The email and telephone values are showing up correctly because there are no spaces, but you should quote those as well just in case.